# Page not found (404) Error on Django:

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

the output we are looking at is to get title on page
http://127.0.0.1:8000/courses/1/1/
and for further pages /2/ or /3/

courses/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render

from .models import Course, Step

def course_list(request):
    courses = Course.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'courses/course_list.html',
                  {'courses': courses})

def course_detail(request, pk):
    course = get_object_or_404(Course, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'courses/course_detail.html',
                  {'course': course})

def step_detail(request, course_pk, step_pk):
    step = get_object_or_404(Step, course_id=course_pk, pk=step_pk)
    return render(request, 'courses/step_detail.html',
                  {'step': step})
```

our focus will be :

```
def step_detail(request, course_pk, step_pk):

    step = get_object_or_404(Step, course_id=course_pk, pk=step_pk)

    return render(request, 'courses/step_detail.html', {'step': step})
```

step_detail.html

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %} {{ step.title }} - {{ step.course.title }}{% endblock %}
     {% block content %}
     <article>
     <h2> {{step.course.title }} </h2>
         <h3> {{step.title }} </h3>
         {{ step.content|linebreaks }}
     </article>
     {% endblock %}
```

course/url.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.course_list),
    url(r'(?P<course_pk>\d+)/(?P<step_pk>\d+)/$', views.step_detail),
    url(r'(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.course_detail),
]
```

Comment: Paste your `models.py` here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, you are getting `404 error` from here.

```
 step = get_object_or_404(Step, course_id=course_pk, pk=step_pk)
```

Here (`get_object_or_404`) you are saying that if unable to find a **Step** with given `course_id` and `step_pk` then give `404` error and it is doing the same.

You need to make sure that the entries exist. 
Your codes seem fine.

Comment: @AshishYadav, did it help?

Comment: No i still working it out. but i do get what you were trying to say. i am posting one more question may be these 2 things are interrelated.

Comment: @AshishYadav, If this answer helped, you can select the answer. Thanks.